# Node rendered HTML file not finding relative path Scripts

Tags: node.js

New to node, and have it running pulling in an HTML page using Express and EJS

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

//load up index file
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render('index.html');
});
```

However the HTML includes some relative path JS scripts

```
 <html>
  ....more...
 <script src="js/libs/jquery.js"></script>
 <script src="js/libs/underscore.js"></script>
 <script src="js/libs/backbone.js"></script>
```

If i run my HTML page via my original "localhost/myProject" it all works fine. However if i launch my file via Node which is set to  "localhost:8080"

```
 app.server.listen(8080);
```

Then it no longer finds the "/js" directory. Is there some sort of configuration that I am missing, or should i go about this another way?

**Update**:
Just found this

```
app.use(express.static( __dirname + '/public' ));
```

might be what I am looking for, although i need to do some refactoring

Comment: Try referencing with `/js...` not just `js...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should configure express to server static files, for example, put all the static files under a directory called 'public'

```
app.configure(function () {
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
    app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
    app.use(app.router);    
});
```

then in your html:

```
    <script src="/public/js/libs/jquery.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I just ran into the static file config. Thanks. Will mark correct once the system allows me to.

Comment: Note that express configure method has been depreciated and doesn't work with 4.X.X