# 500 error when trying to load scripts using express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, syntax-error

I'm trying to load javascript using `<script>` tags.

I'm using the code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16432847/node-rendered-html-file-not-finding-relative-path-scripts), but I think he was getting a 400 error, whereas I am getting a 500 error.

Some of my express code:

```
app.configure(function () {
  app.use(express.bodyParser()); //not sure...
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); 
});
app.set('view options', {
  layout: false
});
```

Snippet of my Index.ejs file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style src="./list.css"></style>
<LINK href="blockStyle.css" title="compact" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">


<script src="/public/js/libs/jquery/jquery-2.0.3"></script>
<script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="/public/js/app.js"></script>
```

Here's some of the output from the terminal:

```
GET /public/js/libs/jquery/jquery-2.0.3 500 9ms
TypeError: Cannot read property 'connect.sid' of undefined
    at Object.session [as handle] (/Users/humble_student/Desktop/ndent/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/session.js:239:32)
    at next (/Users/humble_student/Desktop/ndent/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:193:15)
    at resume (/Users/humble_student/Desktop/ndent/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/static.js:65:7)
    at SendStream.error (/Users/humble_student/Desktop/ndent/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/static.js:80:37)
    at SendStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:126:20)
    at SendStream.error (/Users/humble_student/Desktop/ndent/node_modules/express/node_modules/send/lib/send.js:147:51)
    at SendStream.onStatError (/Users/humble_student/Desktop/ndent/node_modules/express/node_modules/send/lib/send.js:248:48)
    at SendStream.pipe (/Users/humble_student/Desktop/ndent/node_modules/express/node_modules/send/lib/send.js:320:26)
    at Object.oncomplete (fs.js:297:15)
```

Thank you so much! Let me know if there's anything I can do to clarify my question.

EDIT: 
I've tried to set up sessions, but I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly (I was blindly copying code from a tutorial.).

I have:

and in helperLib I have:

```
var MemoryStore = express.session.MemoryStore
var sessionStore = new MemoryStore();
var getSessionstore = function(){ return sessionStore; }
```

EDIT2: 
The problem was that I was missing a .js at the end of all my scripts. Thanks for your help!

Thoughts on why I introduced that bug:

The bug was caused because I was tired of using requireJS, so I copied the paths from there (which omit the .js at the end) into script tags (which require them). I've even identified "copying code instead of writing it from scratch" as a common source of bugs for me. I suppose I need to actually implement this as a check-list to follow (there's a good book about checklists being used in fields where "bugs" cost people's lives called "the Checklist Manifesto").

(Also, I should mention that when I used the cookiestore() stuff, my sockets didn't work.)

Comment: Your public dir is for express to know where files are, so don't include the '/public' in your template.  IIRC, express first checks all requests against the public dir you give it.  Also, are you trying to use sessions?  Did you set Express up to use them?

Comment: That's what I originally thought about sessions, but the question I linked to in the post said to use them. (and I tried it both ways).

Comment: I'm pretty sure sessions isn't causing this, as the error happens when you try to get 'jquery-2.0.3'.  Should there also be a .js at the end of that?  Also, again, don't include '/public' in your index.ejs file. <script src="/public/js/app.js"></script> should just be <script src="/js/app.js"></script> I believe.

Comment: Yeah, I updated the question to say that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try specifying something like the following in your app:

```
app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.session({secret: 'secret', key: 'express.sid'}))
```

Based on what you have shared, it does not seem like you configured express for sessions.

Comment: I copied that line (on top of the line I added in the edited post), and I still get an 500 error.

Comment: do you have the cookie parser - sessions are implemented via cookies

Comment: I don't believe I have the cookie parser. What should it look like?

Comment: one more thing - you may wish to use something like redis or mongo for holding session data as opposed to relying on memorystore that comes with express (memorystore will work properly from a functional perspective)